# How do I properly test a var that changes through a publisher in my viewModel in XCTestCase

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Im trying to test a simple publisher within the Combine framework and SwiftUI.  My test tests a published bool named isValid in my view model.  My view model also has a published username string, that when changes and becomes 3 characters or more isValid is assigned the value.  Here is the view model.  I am sure I am not understanding how publishers work in a test environment, timing etc...  Thanks in advance.

```
public class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var username = ""
  @Published var isValid = false
  private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {
    $username
      .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
      .removeDuplicates()
      .map { input in
        print("~~~> \(input.count >= 3)")
        return input.count >= 3
    }
    .assign(to: \.isValid, on: self)
    .store(in: &disposables)
  }
}
```

Here is my view, not really important here

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var userViewModel = UserViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    TextField("Username", text: $userViewModel.username)
  }
}
```

Here is my test file and single test that fails

```
class StackoverFlowQuestionTests: XCTestCase {
  var model = UserViewModel()

    override func setUp() {
        model = UserViewModel()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
    }

    func testIsValid() {
      model.username = "1"
      XCTAssertFalse(model.isValid)
      model.username = "1234"
      XCTAssertTrue(model.isValid) //<----- THIS FAILS HERE
    }

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason is that view model asynchronous but test is synchronous...

```
$username
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
```

... the `.receive` operator here makes final assignment of `isValid` on the next event cycle of `RunLoop.main`

but the test

```
model.username = "1234"
XCTAssertTrue(model.isValid) //<----- THIS FAILS HERE
```

expects that `isValid` will be changed immediately.

So there are following possible solutions:

1. remove `.receive` operator at all (in this case it is preferable, because it is UI workflow, which is anyway always on main runloop, so using scheduled receive is redundant.

   ```
   $username
       .removeDuplicates()
       .map { input in
           print("~~~> \(input.count >= 3)")
           return input.count >= 3
       }
   .assign(to: \.isValid, on: self)
   .store(in: &disposables)
   ```

Result:

```
model.username = "1234"
XCTAssertTrue(model.isValid) // << PASSED
```

2. make UT wait for one event and only then test `isValid` (in this case it should be documented that `isValid` has asynchronous nature by intention)

   ```
   model.username = "1234"
   RunLoop.main.run(mode: .default, before: .distantPast) // << wait one event
   XCTAssertTrue(model.isValid) // << PASSED
   ```

Comment: I also ran into an issue with testing where I needed to write a test where the publisher used `.debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)`.  I ended up using your second method like this  `RunLoop.main.run(mode: .default, before: Date().addingTimeInterval(3))` and it worked.  Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what i needed ! In my case combine was plugged into legacy synchronous code and just waiting for an expectation wasn't working

Comment: @user1302387 I have spent several hour searching for the right way to deal with this. .debounce was causing all sorts of weird issues inside my testing. This was also the solution!

Answer (score 7):

As @Asperi said: the reason of this mistake is that you receive values asynchronous. I searched a little and found [Apple's tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations) about `XCTestExpectation` usage. So I tried to use it with your code and the tests passed successfully. The other way is to use [Combine Expectations](https://github.com/groue/CombineExpectations).

```swift
class StackoverFlowQuestionTests: XCTestCase {

    var model = UserViewModel()

    override func setUp() {
        model = UserViewModel()
    }

    func testIsValid() throws {

        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "waiting validation")

        let subscriber = model.$isValid.sink { _ in
            guard self.model.username != "" else { return }
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        model.username = "1234"
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
        XCTAssertTrue(model.isValid)

    }

    func testIsNotValid() {

        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "waiting validation")

        let subscriber = model.$isValid.sink { _ in
            guard self.model.username != "" else { return }
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        model.username = "1"
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
        XCTAssertFalse(model.isValid)

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I add all the code and output for clarity. I changed testing validation like in your example (where you test both "1" and "1234" options). And you'll see, that I just copy-paste your model (except name and `public` for variables and `init()`). But still, I **don't have** this mistake:

> *Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 1 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "waiting validation".*

```swift
// MARK: TestableCombineModel.swift file
import Foundation
import Combine

public class TestableModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published public var username = ""
    @Published public var isValid = false
    private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    public init() {
        $username
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main) // as you see, I didn't delete it
            .removeDuplicates()
            .map { input in
                print("~~~> \(input.count >= 3)")
                return input.count >= 3
        }
        .assign(to: \.isValid, on: self)
        .store(in: &disposables)
    }

}

// MARK: stackoverflowanswerTests.swift file:
import XCTest
import stackoverflowanswer
import Combine

class stackoverflowanswerTests: XCTestCase {

    var model: TestableModel!

    override func setUp() {
        model = TestableModel()
    }

    func testValidation() throws {

        let expectationSuccessfulValidation = self.expectation(description: "waiting successful validation")
        let expectationFailedValidation = self.expectation(description: "waiting failed validation")

        let subscriber = model.$isValid.sink { _ in
            // look at the output. at the first time there will be "nothing"
            print(self.model.username == "" ? "nothing" : self.model.username)
            if self.model.username == "1234" {
                expectationSuccessfulValidation.fulfill()
            } else if self.model.username == "1" {
                expectationFailedValidation.fulfill()
            }

        }

        model.username = "1234"
        wait(for: [expectationSuccessfulValidation], timeout: 1)
        XCTAssertTrue(model.isValid)

        model.username = "1"
        wait(for: [expectationFailedValidation], timeout: 1)
        XCTAssertFalse(model.isValid)

    }

}
```

and here is the **output**

```
2020-01-14 09:16:41.207649+0600 stackoverflowanswer[1266:46298] Launching with XCTest injected. Preparing to run tests.
2020-01-14 09:16:41.389610+0600 stackoverflowanswer[1266:46298] Waiting to run tests until the app finishes launching.
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2020-01-14 09:16:41.711
Test Suite 'stackoverflowanswerTests.xctest' started at 2020-01-14 09:16:41.712
Test Suite 'stackoverflowanswerTests' started at 2020-01-14 09:16:41.712
Test Case '-[stackoverflowanswerTests.stackoverflowanswerTests testValidation]' started.
nothing
~~~> true
1234
~~~> false
1
Test Case '-[stackoverflowanswerTests.stackoverflowanswerTests testValidation]' passed (0.004 seconds).
Test Suite 'stackoverflowanswerTests' passed at 2020-01-14 09:16:41.717.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.004 (0.005) seconds
Test Suite 'stackoverflowanswerTests.xctest' passed at 2020-01-14 09:16:41.717.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.004 (0.005) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' passed at 2020-01-14 09:16:41.718.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.004 (0.006) seconds
```

**UPDATE 2** Actually I do catch mistakes of "*Asynchronous wait failed: ...*" if I changed this line of code:

```swift
let subscriber = model.$isValid.sink { _ in
```

to this, as Xcode propose:

```swift
model.$isValid.sink { _ in // remove "let subscriber ="
```

Comment: I tried what you have mentioned here and I am getting an error on line `wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)`.  It is telling me _Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 1 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "waiting validation"._ . I just did a complete copy and paste of your code for clarity's sake.  In the viewModel, I ran the tests with `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)` commented out and left in, and it still doesn't work.  The error changes with that line included or not.  I am assuming we want to remove `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1302387 interesting and unexpected behavior. Please, check updates, maybe there you'll find the answer. But as you can see, I didn't change the model and didn't touch the ```.receive(on: RunLoop.main)``` line of code. At the and you'll see, how did I catch error with async and where was wrong line of code (maybe you followed Xcode's propose too).

Comment: @ Александр I'm still not getting this working using this method.  I error out with `caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "API violation - multiple calls made to -[XCTestExpectation fulfill] ` at the first fulfillment.  It looks like it is happening twice.  My output looks different than yours as well.  Maybe my setup isn't like yours.

Comment: @user1302387 yes, while you're using ```.sink``` it calls for 3 times (you saw my output, there is "nothing" at the first time). Ok, let's check Xcode versions: I tried it at  11.2 (11B52). And even more: I wrote such kind of tests for my project example (at https://github.com/LexHrabovskyi/SimplePlayer). It's interesting for me, why this code doesn't work in your example. Maybe there is some kind of chat at StackOverflow?

Comment: @ Александр I uploaded this test project to my Google drive.  Take a look at it if you want.  I am wondering if my setup is at fault.  I am on 11.3.1.  Thanks for your interest and help here.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CXmppqORErlxoAMZty4LOEBUZAEkuui3

Comment: @user1302387 It's time to update my Xcode and look, how 11.3.1 works. Again, I downloaded your project, ran it on Xcode version 11.2 and all the tests passed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using  [Combine Testing Extensions](https://github.com/industrialbinaries/CombineTestExtensions) to help with Publisher testing and the code looks quite nice:

```
// ARRANGE
let showAlert = viewModel.$showAlert.record(numberOfRecords: 2)

// ACT
viewModel.doTheThing()

// ASSERT
let records = showAlert.waitAndCollectRecords()
XCTAssertEqual(records, [.value(false), .value(true)])
```